# Import pywinauto - No module named application

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywinauto

I have just installed pywinauto. I am using Python 2.7. However, when I try to import pywinauto:

```
    import pywinauto as p
```

I get the following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<ipython-input-3-e7d9e0ea5219>", line 1, in <module>
        import pywinauto as p

    File "pywinauto.py", line 8, in <module>
        from pywinauto.application import Application

    ImportError: No module named application
```

I have checked the library where pywinauto is located and application.py is there including the function Application.

Any ideas to what is wrong?

Comment: Hmm... Very interesting. Which operating system do you use? What is the value of `sys.platform`?

Comment: Hi, I get the following value 'win32'

Comment: Even more strange... How it was installed? `pip install -U pywinauto`? Did you try to reinstall?

Comment: At first: pip install pywinauto , ran my script - got the error - so I  tried pip install --upgrade pywinauto. But it is still a no go...

Comment: Do you have multiple python version installed?

Comment: Can you also check `sys.path` value? It might be broken/emptied by some reason. Does it contain something like `"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages"`?

Comment: @Izzat. Yes, I both have Python 2.7 and Python 3 installed. I primarily use Python 2.7.

Comment: @Vasily. Checking sys.path. 'C:\\Users\\rlc\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages', is included.

Comment: Maybe the python.exe that was used for `python.exe setup.py install` is not Python 2.7. To check, open a command prompt and run `python.exe -V`.

If that is the case, you need to go to the directory where you extracted the pywinauto zip file, and run `C:\python27\python.exe setup.py install`

Comment: It's easy to check which Python is really used by calling `sys.version` in IPython. To re-install pywinauto first run `pip uninstall pywinauto` then `pip install -U pywinauto`.

Comment: To install pywinauto in Python3 run `C:\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe install -U pywinauto` if it's not a default Python on the system.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the support. I'll try and see what I can figure out!

Comment: Hi Vasily. Thanks for the help. I did not manage to get it working in Python 2.7, but now at least in python 3.6!

Comment: OK, will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which Python is really use in IPython (need to check value of `sys.version`).

To install pywinauto in Python3 run `C:\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe install -U pywinauto` if it's not a default Python on the system.

The same for Anaconda Python 2.7 if you have several Py2 installations:

```
C:\Users\rlc\Anaconda2\Scripts\pip.exe install -U pywinauto
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Vasily, just checked again. Your solution only works for Python36 unfortunately not for Python 2.7.

Comment: Maybe Anaconda needs to be re-installed. We've not ever seen such an issue before.